# How can I get Libre Office to not list fonts I have uninstalled.?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, purge

How can I get Libre Office to not list fonts I have uninstalled?  The drop down menu lists all the fonts that were part of the original installation. I want to purge the list of uninstalled fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update font cache, LO might see old information from not up-to-date cache.

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Also, are you sure you did uninstall all copies of fonts?

```
sudo updatedb
locate <fontname>
```